# Compila pero no corre. wxwidgets

Tags: c++, codeblocks, gtk

Que tal. Soy nuevo utilizando esta herramienta.

Estoy tratando de correr un programa en c++, con el plugin de wxsmith en code::blocks. Recien instale wxwidgets, y quise correr un programa con un solo boton, al compilarlo compila sin ningun problema, pero al ejecutarlo obtengo esto:

```
-------------- Run: Debug in test6 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /home/tonny/Documents/Codeblocks Projects/wx/test6/bin/Debug/test6
Executing: /home/tonny/Documents/Codeblocks\ Projects/wx/test6/bin/Debug/test6  (in /home/tonny/Documents/Codeblocks Projects/wx/test6/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

En el directorio aparece el exe para poder ejecutarlo, sin embargo si lo intento correr desde ahi pareciera que no hace nada.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

En estos puntos, cualquier código de cualquier lenguaje tiene que ser revisado poco a poco para ver los fallos en llamadas y relacionados

Comment: En este caso es irrelevante verificar el codigo, ya que si alcanza a compilar pero el exe de salida no lo quiere ejecutar

Comment: No es irrelevante porque por ejemplo, una llamada podría hacer referencia a algo que no viene a cuento. Y esto produce que aunque no funcione, compile

Comment: Tienes razon. Ya pude resolver mi problema. Te invito a que lo leas. Solo eran errores por las versiones del GTK que tenia instaladas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Que tal amigos. Pude resolver mi propio error.

Al obtener el exe de salida despues de compilar, decidí correrlo en el terminal, a lo cual apareció esto:

```
Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
```

Estos errores me dieron debido a que instalé las 2 versiones de GTK con anterioridad, asi como tambien instale la version 2.8 y 3.0.3 de wxWidgets.

Busque la solucion el linea, sin embargo nadie tenia el error parecido a mi, ya que este error por lo regular se da en python, por lo que opté por la solución más obvia: Desinstalar alguno de los paquetes de GTK, ya sea 2.0 ó 3.0, y encontré que lo mejor era borrar la versión 2.0.

POR FAVOR NO LO HAGAN!

Si desinstalan cualquiera de las 2 versiones se desinstalarán muchas dependencias, en mi caso entre las que me di cuenta estaban Firefox, code::blocks y los paquetes para los widgets del GUI principal de ubuntu. Mi sistema quedó horriblemente optimizado por lo que tuve que reinstalarlo.

Al tener mi sistema limpio de nuevo, busqué algún tutorial para instalar todo correctamente y encontre [esto](http://www.guia-ubuntu.com/index.php?title=WxWidgets). Sin embargo es algo viejo y esos paquetes ya no existen en los repositorios por lo que tuve que correr:

```
sudo aptitude install libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-dev wx3.0-headers wx-common
```

De esta manera se descargan todos los paquetes con la version mas estable de wxWidgets (3.0.3)

Por ultimo ejecuté:

```
sudo aptitude install codeblocks libcodeblocks0 libwxsmithlib0 codeblocks-contrib
```

Para instalar code::blocks nuevamente.

Traté de compilar y todo funcionó correctamente!

Moraleja: Nunca instales paquetes de diferentes versiones porque puede dar errores.